# if statement does work in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
IF (5>2) THEN
UPDATE people
set name = 'jacob';
END IF;
```

I am using phpmyadmin query
A statement as simple as that does not execute because of an error. I tried inserting the same code between 'BEGIN AND END' and I get the same error message

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (5 > 2) then

Comment: Really, you can't look at any online example of how to do an IF statement?  It is easier to search "IF mysql" into google than to type your question.

Comment: But the BIGGER problem... if that condition is ever true, or changed to what you really do intend, your update statement will update ALL PEOPLE to the name 'jacob', not just a specific one record... be careful !!!

Answer (score 2):

There is no THEN in sql if statements. The following should work:

```
 IF (5>2) 
 BEGIN
    UPDATE people SET name = 'jacob';
 END
```

Comment: short question. what is 5 and 2. are that values in a field ? if you want this to change only some records you must use WHERE : UPDATE people set name 'Jacob' WHERE (5>2)   .... or WHERE field > 2

Comment: @kaka I have used his code, just changing the UPDATE statement to something that works in my DB, and there are no errors. You need to look at your UPDATE statement if it still does not work for you.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I think he is using (5>2) as a fake to get a true value each time.

Comment: @ Jeff.Clark yes, sure - but i want to know what he want to do. then i can better help